# Next.js Image rendering error: "The requested resource isn't a valid image"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm following the Next.js tutorial (specifically [this one](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/polishing-layout)). The following code sample is a simplified version of the code linked in the tutorial to make this question easier to follow.

`/pages/posts/first-post.js`

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Layout from '../../components/layout';
import Image from 'next/image';
import profilePic from '../../public/images/dp.jpg'


export default function FirstPost() {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Head>
                <title>First Post Woottt</title>
            </Head>
            <h1>First Post</h1>
            <h2>
                <Link href="/">← Back to home</Link>
            </h2>
            <img src="/images/profile.jpg" alt="Your Name" />
            <Image src="/images/profile.jpg" width={100} height={100} />
            <Image src={profilePic} width={100} height={100} />
        </Layout >
    );
}
```

I have an image called `profile.jpg` at the following path: `app-root/public/images/profile.jpg`. I also copied this over to `app-root/public/profile.jpg`

However the image never loads. It returns a 400 with the following error:

```
The requested resource isn't a valid image.
```

On the server side I get a log saying:

```
The requested resource isn't a valid image for /images/profile.jpg received text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Things I've tried so far:

1. Use a regular `<img>` instead of the nextjs `<Image>` and this renders totally fine
2. Copy the image to the root `public` folder and also the corresponding src link, but this doesn't do it
3. Import the image using `import profilePic from '../../public/images/dp.jpg'` and then use it with `src={profilePic}` but this doesn't fix the issue either.
4. Try a different image

Does anyone know what might be going on, or how I can debug this further?

Comment: try `import profilePic from 'public/images/dp.jpg'`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error only when I deploy on IIS with iisnode, not in localhost.
The error happens for release Next later than: 13.4.12

Till this release it works fine.

Since 13.4.13 I have got this error

In localhost it works fine: next build and running node server.js

On IIS:

Using Html pure **img** it works fine.

I tried: Import the image using:
**import** myImage from '../../public/images/....png'
and then use it with src={myImage} but this doesn't fix the issue either.

It does not work and I get the same error error
The error happens when I am deploying to IIS + IISNODE.

It seems that there is a problem with https.

Solution Adopted:

Loading image via base64 and you have to use next/image with:

src={`data:image/png;base64,${myImageBase64}`}

This is a workaround but it works, maybe it is a little slower but you can use this fix till Next.js will give us a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by apply this modification in next.config.js:

images: {
unoptimized: true,
...
}
or just put in the image:
unoptimized

If you try, you should solve.

The optimization is not allowed by iis with iisnode, in release 13.5

I met this problem since release 13.4.13 when I deploy on IIS.

I hope this suggestion could help you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by moving the **images** folder to the **public** folder only.
Do not make any other changes to this code.

```
<Image
              priority
              src="/images/profile.jpg"
              className={utilStyles.borderCircle}
              height={144}
              width={144}
              alt=""
            />
```

I hope this is helpful!